# SLD Polygon Styling in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld

```
<Rule>       
      <Title>EU-SPA</Title>
      <ogc:Filter>
      <PropertyIsEqualTo>
         <PropertyName>BEWERT2006</PropertyName>
         <Literal>EU-SPA</Literal>
      </PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <GraphicFill><Graphic>
            <Mark>
              <WellKnownName>shape://slash</WellKnownName>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#66ff33</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">.7</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
              <Stroke>
                <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
              </Stroke>
              <Stroke />
            </Mark><Size>5</Size>
            </Graphic></GraphicFill>
        </Fill>
        <Stroke/>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

I would like to have a square with slanted lines inside in which the fill must be one colour and the stroke must be another. I have written this code to make it run but it just shows without any colour. Can somebody share some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shape://slash is just a line, it cannot be filled. But a rule can contain multiple  symbolizers that will be superimposed. Try this for example:

```xml
<Rule>       
      <Title>EU-SPA</Title>
      <ogc:Filter>
      <PropertyIsEqualTo>
         <PropertyName>BEWERT2006</PropertyName>
         <Literal>EU-SPA</Literal>
      </PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
         <Fill>
            <CssParameter name="fill">#66ff33</CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">.7</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <GraphicFill><Graphic>
            <Mark>
              <WellKnownName>shape://slash</WellKnownName>
              <Stroke>
                <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
              </Stroke>
              <Stroke />
            </Mark><Size>5</Size>
            </Graphic></GraphicFill>
        </Fill>
        <Stroke/>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

Comment: Thank you :). It worked like a charm.